# Sql statement with random selection and no repeat

Tags: ios, sqlite, random

I have created a quiz game on iOS with an sqlite database.I can retrieve my questions random with their answers correctly but I have two questions. Firstly i would like to know if is it possible to not repeat the same question? And second i would like the player to set the number of the questions that he wants to play. For the second one i created succesfully an alertview with textfield but is it possible to pass the value into the sql statement?
Thank you in advance.

Here is the code for the sql statement that i use for the random questions:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Category IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
```

and all the code is:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) categoriesList{
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Categories.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }


    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Category IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    NSString * insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"UPDATE Questions SET Used='NO'"];
    const char * insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt,-1, &sqlStatement, NULL);

    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Categories * choise = [[Categories alloc] init];

            question.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];

            NSMutableArray  *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            while (arary.count < 4) {
                int value = arc4random()%4+2;
                BOOL isFound = [[arary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
                if(!isFound)
                    [arary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
            }
            answer1.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:0] intValue])];
            answer2.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:1] intValue])];
            answer3.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:2] intValue])];
            answer4.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:3] intValue])];

            NSString * columnName  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_name(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:0] intValue])];

            answer1.tag = ([columnName isEqualToString:@"Answer1"])?999:0;

            columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_name(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:1] intValue])];

            answer2.tag = ([columnName isEqualToString:@"Answer1"])?999:0;


            columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_name(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:2] intValue])];

            answer3.tag = ([columnName isEqualToString:@"Answer1"])?999:0;


            columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_name(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:3] intValue])];

            answer4.tag = ([columnName isEqualToString:@"Answer1"])?999:0;

            answer1btn.tag = answer1.tag;
            answer2btn.tag = answer2.tag;
            answer3btn.tag = answer3.tag;
            answer4btn.tag = answer4.tag;
            [categories addObject:choise];
            [self prepareForIntroAnimation];
            [self performIntroAnimation];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return categories;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What you could do is add a column and have it say YES for used and NO for not used and modify your SQL statement to say `where used=NO` or something of that nature.
2. You could use a String and pass the value into a string then convert it into a char:

   ```
   NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Category IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT %i", [limitTextfield.text intValue]];

   const char *sqlChar = [sqlStr UTF8String];
   ```

EDIT

To answer your comment. In the viewDidLoad you could set the whole "used" column to 'NO' by using

```
UPDATE Questions
SET used = 'NO'
WHERE used = 'YES';
```

So that would reset all of the elements in the column to the default value of 'NO' for the 'YES' part

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Questions SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE questionColumn = '%@' SET used = 'YES'", questionLabel.text intValue];
const char *sqlChar = [sqlStr UTF8String];
```

Comment: Heinst you mean if i understand to add a column in my database, but really i can not understand the YES and NO how will be modified?

Comment: I edited my answer...my SQL is a little rusty so it may not be the exact syntax, but it is close

Comment: i am trying it until now Heist. I really don't understand yet your suggestion.

Comment: What part are you confused about??

Comment: I will edit my post with whole sqlite code and if you can help me how to add your suggestion please?